# Undefined output shape of custom Keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am writing a custom Keras layer that flattens all except the last dimension of the input. However, when feeding the output of the layer into the next layer an error occurs because the output shape of the layer is `None` in all dimensions.

```py
class FlattenLayers( Layer ):
    """
    Takes a nD tensor flattening the middle dimensions, ignoring the edge dimensions.
    [ n, x, y, z ] -> [ n, xy, z ]
    """

    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super( FlattenLayers, self ).__init__( **kwargs )


    def build( self, input_shape ):
        super( FlattenLayers, self ).build( input_shape )


    def call( self, inputs ):
        input_shape = tf.shape( inputs )

        flat = tf.reshape(
            inputs,
            tf.stack( [ 
                -1, 
                K.prod( input_shape[ 1 : -1 ] ),
                input_shape[ -1 ]
            ] )
        )

        return flat


    def compute_output_shape( self, input_shape ):
        if not all( input_shape[ 1: ] ):
            raise ValueError( 'The shape of the input to "Flatten" '
                             'is not fully defined '
                             '(got ' + str( input_shape[ 1: ] ) + '). '
                             'Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" '
                             'or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first '
                             'layer in your model.' )

        output_shape = ( 
            input_shape[ 0 ], 
            np.prod( input_shape[ 1 : -1 ] ), 
            input_shape[ -1 ] 
        )

        return output_shape
```

For example, when a Dense layer follows I receive the error `ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to Dense should be defined. Found None.`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `tf.stack()` in new shape? You want to flatten all dimensions except the last one; this is how you could do it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
import numpy as np

class FlattenLayer(Layer):

    def __init__( self, **kwargs):
        super(FlattenLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build( self, input_shape ):
        super(FlattenLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call( self, inputs):
        new_shape = self.compute_output_shape(tf.shape(inputs))
        return tf.reshape(inputs, new_shape)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        new_shape = (input_shape[0]*input_shape[1]*input_shape[2],
                     input_shape[3])
        return new_shape
```

Testing with a single data point (`tf.__version__=='1.13.1'`):

```py
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, 10, 1))    
res = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=2)(inputs)
res = FlattenLayer()(res)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=res)

x_data = np.random.normal(size=(1, 10, 10, 1))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    evaled = model.outputs[0].eval({model.inputs[0]:x_data})
    print(evaled.shape) # (81, 3)
```

Comment: I had `stack` in there because I was modifying a previous example that used it. Thanks for the input. 

I just tried to run your code on Google Colab and received the error below on the line `self.compute_output_shape`:
`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'method'> to Tensor. Contents: <bound method Kernel.raw_input of <google.colab._kernel.Kernel object at 0x7fd3589baf98>>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`
I'm running TF v 1.13.1. 

Also, the error is coming when feeding the custom layer into another, not vice versa, as you have done in your example.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the exact same example? Copy paste this exact code and remove all other code that you have and reload the runtime. You probably passing wrong variable to the model's input.

Comment: You were correct. It was an issue with the runtime. I got my layer working with the help of your code as an example, thank you. However, I still seem to be lacking an understanding of why my original code did not work, because I am struggling with the same issue for another custom layer now. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to ensure custom layers output all the relevant shape information.

Comment: 1. You can't use `np.prod()` with arguments got from `tf.shape()`. 2.  You compute incorrectly the new shape. Compute new shape as I do - explicitly write each element in product without slicing. 3. The resulted shape, if it is fed to the dense layer, must have two dimensions. In your code you have 3 dimensions. The first dimension can be undefined (`None`), but the second dimension cannot be `None`, because it determines the first dimension of the weight matrix.